# List Multisite Dashboards on Admin Sidebar

Tags: wordpress

[image: Dashboard links go here!]

I've only got two or three sites, and it's driving me batty to always have to click on 'My Sites' then on the 'Dashboard' link to navigate around between them.

How can I add these dashboard links directly to this section?

**EDIT**: My hope would be across all the site dashboards, not just the network admin. I believe this will have to be a plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/admin-menu-editor/